# parallax scrolling cocos2d - object that comes once in min

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, parallax

I try create game use parallax scroll, I put sprites in the screen and after it the same sprites again, when first sprite go out of the screen I move it to the end of the sprite that in the screen. one of my sprites is a sun, I want show him once in minute. what is the better way to implement the parallax scrolling with the sun? when the sun go out of the screen place him before the screen with distance or use timer or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise to use a timer. It's not too much of a hassle, so I would not say this is premature optimization. You will avoid the (really low) overhead of having a sprite moving outside the screen when there is no need to do so.